# What may cause parallel traffic from an iDevice and a computer in mavericks 10.1?

Tags: iphone, macos, apache

I'm trying to debug a problem in our system and am experiencing some very weird logging.

For some of the people experiencing the bug, I see two events logged with a short and equall time-distance, always from the same ip.

One is from a computer running OSX 10.1, Safari and one is a few seconds later from an iPhone 7 or iPhone 8.1. What might cause this? It's triggered by fairly many of our users?

Comment: [Handoff](https://www.apple.com/ios/whats-new/continuity/)? Although that'd be iOS 8 only.